# A non-negative synonym for indifferent?

Tags: synonyms

What is a word for being indifferent but not in a negative way?

When I look for synonyms all the words are negative, meaning "I don't care" or apathetic. But that's not what I want.

I want a word that describes someone who believes it doesn't matter who you are, what you like, who you love. Someone who lives life believing everyone is entitled to their opinion and doesn't get stressed out or angry when things don't go exactly to plan. Someone who goes with the flow.

Is there a word for this that's not negative?

Comment: Although etymologically the prefix is negating one, *[detached](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/detached)* has strongly positive connotations, at least among Buddhists.

Comment: _Disinterested_ (as distinguished from _uninterested_), which is negative, is usually used in describing an impartial observer or auditor. The _interest_ is not mental or emotional, but financial; _a disinterested party_ means a person with no financial stake in the outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel the word *indifferent* is about as neutral as you can get, but in consideration of your third paragraph, perhaps you want a word like *laid-back* or one of its synonyms?

From Oxford:

> *informal*
>   Relaxed and easygoing. ‘a shaggy dog with an engaging, laid-back temperament’
>
> Synonyms: relaxed, at ease, easy-going, equable, free and easy, easy, casual, informal,
>   friendly, nonchalant, insouciant, unexcitable, imperturbable,
>   unemotional, unruffled, blasé, blithe, cool, collected, cool, calm,
>   and collected, calm, composed, self-possessed, level-headed,
>   self-controlled, unperturbed, unflustered, unworried, unconcerned,
>   placid, peaceful, tranquil, serene, low-key, understated, downbeat

Answer (score 1):

Such a person is **impartial** (though this doesn't cover all aspects of your description)

not prejudiced towards or against any particular side or party; fair; unbiased

[[Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/impartial)]

synonyms from [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/impartial):

> unbiased, unprejudiced, neutral, non-partisan, non-discriminatory,
>   anti-discrimination, disinterested, uninvolved, uncommitted, detached,
>   dispassionate, objective, open-minded, equitable, even-handed, fair,
>   fair-minded, just

An even more general descriptor is **reasonable**.

> When someone is *reasonable*, they behave in a fair and sensible way.

[[Collins Cobuild](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reasonable)]